# Tried calling: ancestorStateOfType(Instance of 'TypeMatcher<NavigatorState>'

Tags: dart, flutter, navigator

I am trying to call new page on tap of row item in the list view, I am very new to flutter

```js
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title: "My First Flutter App", home: new Home());
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Hello"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: WordPairState()._buildSugg(context));
  }
}

class WordPairState extends State<RandomWordPair> {
  final _suggetions = <WordPair>[];
  final _bigText = const TextStyle(fontSize: 16);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _wordPair = WordPair.random();
    // TODO: implement build
    return Text(_wordPair.asPascalCase);
  }

  Widget _buildSugg(BuildContext ctx) {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          if (i.isOdd) return Divider();

          final count = i ~/ 2;

          if (count >= _suggetions.length) {
            _suggetions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10));
          }

          return _buildRow(_suggetions[count], count, ctx);
        });
  }

  Widget _buildRow(WordPair wp, final count, BuildContext ctx) {
    return ListTile(
        subtitle: Text("List Sub title " + wp.toString()),
        title: Text(
          wp.asPascalCase,
          style: _bigText,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute());

          Navigator.push(context, route);
        });
  }
```

**I am getting an Error as follows maybe it's because of the wrong context but I don't know which context should I pass:**

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (15113): **The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:**
I/flutter (15113): The method 'ancestorStateOfType' was called on null.
I/flutter (15113): Receiver: null
I/flutter (15113): Tried calling: ancestorStateOfType(Instance of 'TypeMatcher')
I/flutter (15113): 
I/flutter (15113): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (15113): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
I/flutter (15113): #1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1376:19)
I/flutter (15113): #2      WordPairState._buildRow. (package:flutter_app/main.dart:99:19)
I/flutter (15113): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:513:14)
I/flutter (15113): #4      _InkResponseState.build. (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:568:30)
I/flutter (15113): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:120:24)
I/flutter (15113): #6      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
I/flutter (15113): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:204:7)
I/flutter (15113): #8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
I/flutter (15113): #9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:20)
I/flutter (15113): #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:192:22)
I/flutter (15113): #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:149:7)
I/flutter (15113): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
I/flutter (15113): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:85:7)
I/flutter (15113): #17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:223:10)
I/flutter (15113): #18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:144:5)
I/flutter (15113): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter (15113): 
I/flutter (15113): Handler: onTap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug/typo in the method

```dart
 Widget _buildRow(WordPair wp, final count, BuildContext context) { // you named it ctx (and using context in implementation) which was causing the problem
    return ListTile(
        subtitle: Text("List Sub title " + wp.toString()),
        title: Text(
          wp.asPascalCase,
          style: _bigText,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute());

          Navigator.push(context, route);
        });
  }
```